# Why i cannot restore the packed data when i use bytes?

Tags: python, struct, byte

```
import struct
x = struct.pack('i', 10)
print(x)
```

result:

```
b'\n\x00\x00\x00'
```

if i want to convert `b'\n\x00\x00\x00'` to and integer it works:

```
bytes_to_convert = b'\n\x00\x00\x00'
bytes_converter = int.from_bytes(bytes_to_convert, byteorder='little', signed=False)
print(bytes_converter)
```

result:

```
10
```

everything's working perfectly but when it comes to `bytes()` function :

```
print(bytes('10', 'utf-16'))
```

if i want to convert it to an integer:

i get this value : `206161706751`

Where is the difference between using `bytes()` and using `struct` to pack data into bytes i used i in `struct` means `4 bytes` and bytes is using `4 bytes` what is the difference ?

Comment: `'10'` is not the same as `10`. `bytes('10', 'utf-16')` is equivalent to `"10".encode('utf-16')` ... each char of the string is a byte (2) and then utf16 encoding seems to add a head and tail to bring it up to 4 bytes.  Why do you think this would be the inverse of struct.pack?  I can't see any relation between them

Comment: you said every char in bytes() is onsistent of 4 bytes right ? why when i use two numbers in bytes('11') i get less bytes ??????

Comment: TBH I don't really understand what `.encode('utf-16')` is doing (and why are you using utf16?) but if we're talking ASCII chars only, and not emojis etc, then each char in your input string "10" is a byte.

Comment: so from what i understand is bytes() for texts converting ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10` is a number ("ten"), which is stored in your computer as `00000000 00001010`

`'10'` is a string, consisting of symbols `1` and `0`. It is stored as `00110000 00110001`.

From the computer's standpoint, there's nothing in common between these two pieces of data. Yes, the string `'10'` happens to be a *name* for the number ten (in our language, at least), but this connection only exists in our brain. The computer is not aware of it.

Comment: so from what i understand is : struct is used to convert numbers to bytes but bytes() function used to convert texts to bytes and transfer them both struct and bytes function use bytes to convert data but each one of these fucntions used in defferent scenarios am i right ?

Comment: yes, this is basically correct.